# Bind Highchart to variable, all within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

To preface this, I am very new to highcharts/javascript/jquery in general, so I apologize if this is a simple question.

I am trying to bind this highchart to a variable, while keeping the $(div class="chart") element on the outside. This is basically part of a bigger loop that creates a new div for each chart. Is this even possible?

```
                $('<div class="chart">')
                .appendTo('#container')
                .highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'line',
                        zoomType: 'xy',
                        animation: false,
                        height: 500
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        line: { marker: { enabled: false } },
                        series: {
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            animation: false,
                            point: { events: { click: function () { conf.zoom.t = this.x.floor(); $scope.updateZoom(); } } },
                            turboThreshold: 0,
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        title: { text: 'Time' }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: { text: 'Value' }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        crosshairs: true,
                        shared: true,
                        animation: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Housekeeping'
                    }
                  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this to store the chart in a variable.

```
var chartOptions = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'some unique selector for the container',
                        type: 'line',
                        zoomType: 'xy',
                        animation: false,
                        height: 500
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        line: { marker: { enabled: false } },
                        series: {
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            animation: false,
                            point: { events: { click: function () { conf.zoom.t = this.x.floor(); $scope.updateZoom(); } } },
                            turboThreshold: 0,
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        title: { text: 'Time' }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: { text: 'Value' }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        crosshairs: true,
                        shared: true,
                        animation: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Housekeeping'
                    }
                  };
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);`
```

This will assign a new chart to a variable and render it to the element specified in the chartOptions.chart.renderTo selector.

You would need to add an id (or some other way to select a single element for the chart to render to) to the  element. If this is part of a loop you could use a loop index as the id to give each div a unique id and then add the index to the renderTo attribute mentioned above.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help